# Image and Video Slider in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-imageview

I am creating an android app with a heterogeneous layout.

The app has a login page where the user logins by entering his license key. After login is verified the user is shifted to next screen.

On the next screen we have displayed a slider.

The problem is that we want to display images and videos in a single slider. So, that after image a video may occur or after some images a video may accour.

Now the real problem is that the slider skips all the images and shows only the video.

We want to show image for an interval of 3 seconds and if a video comes then it should stop the slider and play the entire video and then proceed to the next slide.

Below is our code for the app that we are creating.

```
package com.cd.layout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    private static final int BUTTON_5 = 5;
    List<String> image_ext = Arrays.asList("png","jpeg");
    List<String> video_ext = Arrays.asList("wmv","mp4");
    private int region = 1;
    Bitmap bm;
    String [] splits;   
    String [] media ;
    ArrayList<String> media_path = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> media_path1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> media_type = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> duration = new ArrayList<String>();
    int p = 0 ;
    String media_info [] = null;
    String response_data = null;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        generateView();
    }
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            Log.i("bitmap",bitmap.toString());
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    private static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return inputStream;
    }
    private void generateView() {   

        final CompositeView View7 = new CompositeView(this);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();       
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        final BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        if(region>0) //images/upload/videos/VID-20140111-WA0002.mp4=mp4=00:00:00
        {
            response_data = "images/upload/images/Penguins.jpg=jpeg=00:00:05,images/upload/images/Jellyfish.jpg=jpeg=00:00:05,images/upload/videos/VID-20140111-WA0002.mp4=mp4=00:00:00";   
            media = response_data.split(",");
            for(String s : media)
            {
                media_info = s.split("=");                      
                media_path.add(media_info[0]);
                media_type.add(media_info[1]);
                duration.add(media_info[2]);
            }

            for(p = 0 ; p<=media_type.size()-1; p++)
            {
                if(image_ext.contains(media_type.get(p)))
                {       
                    View7.getImageView().invalidate();
                    View7.getImageView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    View7.getVideoView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    String url = "http://test.com/".concat(media_path.get(p));  //we have removed the live site URL which fetched the video and images and entered the dummy link   
                    Log.i("Image Name",url);
                    final Bitmap bm = loadBitmap(url, bmOptions);   
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override
                        public void run() { 

                            View7.getImageView().setImageBitmap(bm);
                            View7.setId(BUTTON_5);  
                        }
                     }, 50000); 
                    View7.getImageView().setImageBitmap(bm);
                    View7.setId(BUTTON_5);  
                }
                else
                {
                    if(video_ext.contains(media_type.get(p)))
                    {                   
                        View7.getVideoView().invalidate();
                        View7.getVideoView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        View7.getImageView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        String videoToPlay = "http://test.com/".concat(media_path.get(p)); //we have removed the live site URL which fetched the video and images and entered the dummy link
                        Log.i("Image Name",videoToPlay); 
                        View7.getVideoView().setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoToPlay));
                        View7.getVideoView().setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                        View7.getVideoView().setFocusable(true);
                        View7.getVideoView().start();
                    }
                }               
            }   
            region --;
        }       
    final RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                final int oneUnitWidth = mainLayout.getMeasuredWidth() / 8;
                final int oneUnitHeight = mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
                String str = "348:243:320:240:";
                splits = str.split(":");
                count = splits.length;
                if(count!=0)
                {
                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams weatherParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            Integer.parseInt(splits[i]), Integer.parseInt(splits[i+1]));

                    weatherParams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 2);
                    View7.setLayoutParams(weatherParams);
                    count = count - 2;
                    i = i + 2;
                }
                else 
                {
                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams weatherParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            320, 240);

                    weatherParams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 2);
                    View7.setLayoutParams(weatherParams);
                }



                ViewTreeObserver obs = mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

        mainLayout.addView(View7);


    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated..!

Comment: Did u resolved this issue ??

Comment: Yes! issue is resolved.

Comment: I make a view pager to show video and image at the same concept of you, could you help me if you solved the problem? @Yogesh Pawar

Comment: I also have require same functionality. can you help with it @ Yogesh Pawar

Comment: Hi @NiteshRathod, sorry unfortunately I was not able to find a feasible solution for it. In the end we had dropped this featured from our app.

Comment: @ Yogesh Pawar , Somehow i have implemented it. Thanks for your reply.